# online calculator for $\Omega(n)$

Tags: number-theory

I’m looking for an online calculator for $\Omega(n)$, that is, the number of prime factors of $n$, counting multiplicity. I’ve done a google search, but can only find discussion of the function, not implementation of the function.

Comment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ just do something like len(list(factor(6))) for example.

Comment: [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) has `bigomega`.

Comment: WolframAlpha has BigOmega[] too.